# Switching from pts/0 to tty1 or tty2

Tags: linux, python, tty

My friend made some Python scripts which are ran on tty1. 
As shown here after ps -ef command:

```
root      1671     1  0 11:42 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 console
root      1673     1  0 11:42 tty2     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
```

I just want to see, what that Python script does or if there is any way to check source code of an exact python script that is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ps -ef` output doesn't actually show any Python scripts; all it shows is the standard Linux login-prompt program (getty). If a Python program were actually running, it'd usually show up as `python /path/to/the_script.py`, at which point you could just open the same path in a text editor.

On the other hand, if you have an unknown *command*, you can use `which` or `type` to see the file behind it (which may be a Python script or something else).